# How to refresh a prototype app (actually a bookmark on the homescreen) in iOS 7?

Tags: php, ios7, tap, fireworks

I'm using TAP and Fireworks to prototype an iOS app. I'm optimizing my prototype for use on an iPad mini and I recently (maybe mistakenly) upgraded the mini to iOS7.

Now when I add the prototype to my homescreen it has its new icon, but when I open it ..it shows old content. :(

Then when I return to the homescreen the old icon is back too.

I've cleared the cache, cleared the browsing history, restarted the iPad, changed the code on the index page of the site... nothing I try seems to work.
**Is there a secret cache I can clear somewhere?**

ps - I'm a designer, not much of a coder, but if I need to add a line of code to my exported php files I could do that.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that in Safari the changes show up, but in the bookmark I get the cached version.

Comment: Workaround: increment the name of the directory on my server